# Do ANOVAs and correlations require exclusively matched or unmatched data?

Tags: r, correlation, anova, model, matching

I have data which contain matched and unmatched data points.

*I want to know if it is appropriate to do the ANOVA and correlation analysis I have performed below.*

I have "readout" data from 40 subjects. The data come from 3 timepoints; "start", "mid", and "end". Subjects 1 thru 20 contributed data at "start" and "mid", whereas subjects 21 thru 41 contributed data only at "end". Below is the `r` code to generate the dataframe.

**In:**

```
set.seed(1)

long_df <-
  data.frame("subject" = c(rep(x = 1:20, times = 2), 21:40),
             "time" = c(rep(c("start", "mid", "end"), each = 20)),
             "readout" = c(start <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 5, sd = 1),
                           start + rnorm(n = 20, mean = 1, sd = 0.2),
                           rnorm(n = 20, mean = 10, sd = 1)))
```

Performing an ANOVA reveals a significant overall effect of "time", however not without a warning indicating that since some subjects contribute more than one data point, they are given new, unique IDs in the process of performing the ANOVA.

**In:**

```
library(ez)

ezANOVA(data = long_df, dv = readout, wid = subject, between = time)$ANOVA$p
```

**Out:**

```
Warning: Converting "subject" to factor for ANOVA.
Warning: The column supplied as the wid variable contains non-unique values across levels of the supplied between-Ss variables. Automatically fixing this by generating unique wid labels.
[1] 2.400737e-25
```

Performing a *dependent-samples* t-test on "start" vs. "mid" reveals a significant difference.

**In:**

```
wide_df <-
  reshape(data = long_df,
          idvar = "subject",
          timevar = "time",
          direction = "wide")

t.test(wide_df$readout.start, wide_df$readout.mid, paired = TRUE)$p.value
```

**Out:**

```
[1] 3.366883e-16
```

Also, performing an *independent-samples* t-test on "mid" vs. "end" yields a significant difference.

**In:**

```
t.test(wide_df$readout.mid, wide_df$readout.end, paired = FALSE)$p.value
```

**Out:**

```
[1] 3.79291e-17
```

Converting "start", "mid", and "end" to ordinal ranks and performing a Kendall's correlation reveals that I have a significant correlation.

**In:**

```
long_df_for_corr <- long_df

long_df_for_corr$time <- c(rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 20))

cor.test(long_df_for_corr$time, long_df_for_corr$readout, method = "kendall")$p.value
```

**Out:**

```
[1] 2.813639e-12
```

Woohoo! I have a bunch of significant findings, right?! But I'm paranoid and skeptical about the misuse of inferential statistics... I feel like I'm doing this all wrong...

Is it appropriate to do this ANOVA and/or correlation analysis since the "start" and "mid" data are related, but the "end" data are not related to either of the other two?

I will probably post another question, related to this one, about how to perform inferential statistics between two groups when the data in those two groups contain both matched and unmatched data (i.e., when neither a dependent-samples nor an independent-samples t-test is appropriate).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is unclear.  You haven't shown the output and the question may be off topic because it focuses on software implementation.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, thanks for your feedback, and I apologize if the question is not clear.

My question is: is it appropriate to do correlation analysis when some of the data points are "dependent"/"matched" within the dataset while other data are "independent"?

In my example, I have data from 20 people at "start" and "mid" timepoints, and another 20 people only at the "end" timepoint.

The `r` code above is meant to help provide an example of such a dataset, but the answer to my question is not dependent on the implementation of any specific software.