# t-test when data is a mixed of matched and unmatched

Tags: t-test, model, independence, matching, inference

I want to know how to perform a t-test (or other parametric alternative) to determine if two groups are different from one another in the case when I have some data which are matched/dependent-samples and other data which are unmatched/indepenedent samples.

Example:
I have the bodyweights of people before and after a 6-month exercise/diet program.

For some of those people, I have their bodyweight at both timepoints ("before" and "after"). These data are matched/dependent-samples. I will call these data "subset A".

For other people, I have their bodyweight only at one timepoint or the other ("before" or "after", but not both). These data are unmatched/independent-samples. I will call these data "subset B".

If I *only* had subset A, I would do a paired/matched/dependent-samples t-test.

If I *only* had subset B, I would do an unpaired/unmatched/independent-samples t-test.

Since I have the entire dataset, what is the best way forward? I think performing either kind of t-test on the entire dataset is fundamentally wrong since the underlying assumptions of the test must be violated if all samples are not either matched or unmatched.

I have posted a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271999/do-anovas-and-correlations-require-exclusively-matched-or-unmatched-data) regarding how to perform ANOVAs or regressions on data containing matched and unmatched data, but I suspect the questions are different enough to warrant different answers.

Comment: It might be effect to do a independent groups-style analysis but include a robust SE. In STATA you might do `regress weight prepost, robust`